# Получить время простоя, timestamp (алгоритм)

Tags: php, алгоритм, время, datetime, timestamp

У нас есть общая система управления заказами, заказами управляют операторы, 
операторы могут приходить\уходить когда им захочется, наша задача это отследить время когда ни один из операторов не был онлайн, что мы имеем:

База данных с такими таблицами:

```
Operators('id', 'name' ...)

Operator_log('operator_id', 'status(1 = logged, 0 = logout)', 'time')
```

`Operator_log` имеет примерно такие записи:

```
 operator_id |   status   |     time

      1            1         1511541300

      2            1         1511541800

      1            0         1511545876

      5            1         1511581300

      2            0         1511591300

      5            0         1511841300

      4            1         1511941300

      4            0         1512541300
```

Из этих записей видно что простой был между

```
          5            0         1511841300  (3 с конца запись)
```

и

```
          4            1         1511941300  (2 с конца запись)
```

В этот момент ни один из операторов не был онлайн

И вот вопрос, как получить этот простой программно?

Comment: "Из этих записей видно"? Остается сформулировать каким образом это видно и реализовать.

Comment: Именно это мне и нужно , конечно , я не так долго сидел над этой проблемой , но всё же мне так и не пришла идеальная идея, возможно кто-то с таким уже сталкивался и у него есть оптимальный ответ

Comment: Я уверен, что вы не медитируете над логом, а потом через 40 минут выдаете "простой был тут", следовательно вы сознательно действуете по алгоритму. Остается его сформулировать и реализовать, бОльшая часть решения у вас уже есть

Comment: Хм. Не знаю, как бы я стал решать подобную задачу на SQL-сервере, однако если нужно просто алгоритм набросать, то сходу приходит в голову простой алгоритм, разве что лучше таблицы перевести в немного иной формат.

Comment: Я прочитал Ваш ответ и он мне понравился , с такой точки зрения я ещё не смотрел, не знаю на сколько он поможет мне, но всё равно спасибо . Таблицы переводить в другой формат нет возможности , вообще нет возможности работать с данными таблицы только выборка и всё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует два типа отчётов: отчёт на дату и отчёт за период, у вас отчёт второго типа -- за период. В качестве входных данных вам поступит временной интервал "построить отчёт с 08:00:00 01.12.2017 по 18:00:00 01.12.2017".

Вот уже сразу на выход вашего отчёта можете передавать массив интервалов, когда никого не было: сразу первым же оператором записываете в $result первый элемент, содержащий весь период, который передали на вход.

Данные у вас находятся в виде "оператор - статус", но гораздо удобнее было бы обрабатывать данные в виде "оператор - дата начала смены - дата конца смены", например "Иванов был онлайн с 07:00:00 01.12.2017 по 08:15:00 01.12.2017", "Петров был онлайн с 17:00:00 01.12.2017 по 18:15:00 01.12.2017" и "Иванов был онлайн с 09:00:00 01.12.2017 по 09:15:00 01.12.2017".

Вы должны в цикле для каждого заданного периода активности оператора проделать следующие шаги: найти возможные пересечения с элементами результирующего массива.

Пересечения бывают двух видов: когда интервал активности оператора полностью находится внутри элемента (например, оператор был активен с 09:00 по 09:15) и нужно заменить в ответе один элемент (08:00 - 18:00) на два (08:00 - 09:00 и 09:15 - 18:00) или когда интервал активности убирает часть интервала.

Таких вариантов два:

- убирает снизу (от интервала 08:00 - 09:00 убирая активность с 07:00 - 08:15 остаётся интервал 08:15 - 09:00);
- убирает сверху (от интервала 09:15 - 18:00 убирая активность 17:00 - 18:15 остаётся 09:15 - 17:00).

Все условия тривиальны. Допустим, для случая когда у нас есть интервал (ts1_beg, ts1_end) и (ts2_beg, ts2_end) очевидно, что интервал 1 полностью содержится в интервале 2 при условии что ts1_beg > ts2_beg && ts1_end < ts2_end.

По окончании цикла вернуть $result.

В примере, который я приводил, итогом будет являться два периода простоя:

- 08:15 - 09:00
- 09:15 - 17:00
  *